# AWS CLI JMESPath Query to get details of get-execution-history using --query option

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-step-functions, jmespath

I am trying to execute below cli command to get the execution details of the stepfunction

```
aws stepfunctions get-execution-history --execution-arn <TestArn> --no-paginate --output json --query 'events[*].executionStartedEventDetails.input'
```

and above command is returning value in string format

```
"{\"comment\": \"TestComments\", \"inputs\": {\"name1\": \"TestName\", \"name2\": \"TestName1\", \"params\": \"-LOG_LOC testPath\"}}"
```

I am trying to get the value of below keys using --query option but not able to find the way to extract the details from the string object.

```
comment
inputs.name1
inputs.name2
inputs.params.-LOG_LOC
```

I tried to run below queries but it is returning blank object

```
For comment
     --query 'events[*].executionStartedEventDetails.input.comment'

For inputs.name1
     --query 'events[*].executionStartedEventDetails.input.inputs.name1'

For inputs.name2
     --query 'events[*].executionStartedEventDetails.input.inputs.name2'

For inputs.params.-LOG_LOC
     --query 'events[*].executionStartedEventDetails.input.inputs.params'
```

Sample JSON :-

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "timestamp": 1212121212,
            "type": "ExecutionStarted",
            "id": 1,
            "previousEventId": 0,
            "executionStartedEventDetails": {
                "input": "{\"comment\": \"TestComments\", \"inputs\": {\"name1\": \"TestName\", \"name2\": \"TestName1\", \"params\": \"-LOG_LOC testPath\"}}",
                "inputDetails": {
                    "truncated": false
                },
                "roleArn": "ARN"
            }
        }
    ]    
}
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that the value of  the attribute *input* is a string `"input": "{\"comment\": ... }"`. You expect a dictionary `"input": {"comment": ... }` Solve this problem first.

Comment: @VladimirBotka :- I am facing issue on parsing the string only.. if possible help me on how to modify the query so that it will read string value

Comment: Where do you want to parse the input? Is it a command line? A Python script? Ansible play? Anything else?

Comment: @VladimirBotka :- in the --query from aws cli, -- query accepts Jmespath query

Comment: JmesPath is not able to parse JSON. In a command line, you can use *jq*. See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like `jq` to convert the inline json to a json object.
Here's an example:

```bash
aws stepfunctions get-execution-history --execution-arn <TestArn> --no-paginate --output json --query 'events[*].executionStartedEventDetails.input' | jq "fromjson"
```

will give:

```
{
  "comment": "TestComments",
  "inputs": {
    "name1": "TestName",
    "name2": "TestName1",
    "params": "-LOG_LOC testPath"
  }
}
```

you can then easily extract whatever key you need, e.g.:

```bash
aws stepfunctions get-execution-history --execution-arn <TestArn> --no-paginate --output json --query 'events[*].executionStartedEventDetails.input' | jq "fromjson | .comment, .inputs.name1, .inputs.name2"
```

```
"TestComments"
"TestName"
"TestName1"
```

Comment: : Thanks for the reply, I am able to get the required value using jq but not allowed to use it so need to find the solution with jmesPath.

Comment: @SwapnilM Why are you not allowed to use it? You can't do this with jmes only because you can't deserialize json with it